# Wordpress registration plugin that checks pin code before accepting registration

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 50, 000 unique pin codes generated, i will be distributing these to people. i need a plugin that checks the pincode upon registration. if the pincode is correct, the user can register if not they cannot register. user can only register pincode once.

register plus redux plugin has this but i need a plugin that i can upload the pincodes to the db.redux only allows manual upload of pincodes

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know PHP and don't want to learn it, then you have to use that existing plugin. There's probably no need for much coding anyway. (Stackoverflow is for programmers btw, not for free codez.)

Just format your pin code data as CSV file, and use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://www.google.de/search?q=LOAD+DATA+INFILE+mysql) to merge it into the database table and structure the plugin expects. Use Calc/Excel for the CSV formatting, and phpMyAdmin to issue the MySQL command for inserting the data.